# If $U(f,P) = L(f,P)$, show that $f$ is constant.

Tags: integration, analysis, continuity

The question has two part,

1. Show that if f : [a, b] → R is continuous and there exists a partition P of [a,b] such that U(f,P) = L(f,P), then f is constant.
2. Is this true if we drop the assumption that f is continuous?

I've already finished the proof of first question by using the Intermediate Value Theorem.(since the sup and inf of a continuous function are equal on each subinterval, then the function is constant on each subinterval. With the assumption that f is continuous, then we can conclude that f is constant in its domain.)

As for the second question, it seems to be false since if f is not continuous, the Mean Value theorem cannot be applied. However, I cannot think of a counter example or proof for this. Could anyone give a hint?

Comment: Did you mean the intermediate value theorem for the first question?  The mean value theorem is a statement about differentiable functions.

Comment: Yes!Thanks for pointing out this and sry about the confusion. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f$ be Riemann integrable and that there is a parition $P : 0= x_0 < x_1 < \cdots <x_n = 1$ so that $U(f, P) = L(f, P)$.

This mean that for all $i = 1, \cdots n$, we have

$$\sup_{x\in [x_{i-1}, x_i]} f(x) = \inf_{x\in [x_{i-1}, x_i]} f(x)$$

That is, $f$ is constant on $[x_{i-1}, x_i]$. As the intervals contains the end points, one can show that $f$ is constant. Thus it has nothing to do with continuity of $f$.

Comment: Yes, I finished the first part using the same method as you.

Comment: @lulu: And continuity of $f$ is not used at all. So that answers your question 2.

Comment: Can you explain more how we know that if f is constant on each subinterval, then f is constant on the whole domain without being continuous?

Comment: @lulu: One can do that step by step. Say as $f(x) = C$ on $[0, x_1]$ and $f(x) = D$ on $[x_1, x_2]$, then $D = f(x_1) = C$.